# Export composite RGB image with spatial information, R

Tags: r, gis

I am processing hundreds of 4-band images in R and need help on what is probably a very simple task.  As part of the processing, I need to export a single band RGB composite that maintains the spatial information of the original GeoTiff.  In other software I've exported a .jgw file but I need to be able to do this in R.  These images will be used as basemaps and fed into another mapping interface.  I have searched and searched and can only find how to plotRGB() and how to writeRaster().  PlotRGB loses the spatial information and writeRaster() produces a multi-band image.

Any ideas? There is a built in raster in R that can be used.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
x <- RGB(r)
plotRGB(x)  #Is there a way to output this where it will maintain spatial information?
writeRaster(x, filename="file.tif")  #This produces a 3-band tiff, not a composite
```

Answer (score 2):

The `writeRaster` function can take an `options` argument to pass options to the underlying GDAL library (e.g., GeoTIFF options are documented [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html)).  The option `TFW=YES` writes out a `.tfw` world file which appears to be the same thing as a `.jgw` file.

Now, "composite RGB" isn't standard terminology in the TIFF world; it seems to be specific to "ArcMap" and friends, so it's hard to tell what's really meant by this, but you can generate what one would normally think of as a "standard" RGB TIFF format by specifying that the datatype for the color components be 1-byte unsigned integers (`datatype="INT1U"`), so the following may do what you want:

```
writeRaster(RGB(r), filename="file2.tif", datatype="INT1U",
    options="TFW=YES", format="GTiff")
```

As far as I can tell, unrecognized or misspelled `options` values don't generate any error messages, so you need to be careful they're all spelled correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I realized I should be able to pass arguments from GDAL, but I didn't know how.  The script you provided did produce the TFW, which is perfectly acceptable, but the TIFF is still three band rather than one.  I would like to somehow create a single band composite instead.  If you are familiar with QGIS or ArcMap, this would be similar to exporting a raster using the renderer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with QGIS or ArcMap.  And, unfortunately, the term "composite RGB" seems to be specific to that software/field, rather than standard terminology in the TIFF world, so it's hard to tell what they mean from a technical point of view..  However, it looks like specifying `datatype="INT1U"` generates a more typical RGB TIFF which may be what's meant by "composite RGB", so I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for revisiting this.  I tried the modification you made, but it still generated a 3-band image.  I've also heard the output I'm looking fro as "merge channels" or "merge bands."  This link might better explain what I'm looking for: http://gisgeography.com/arcgis-composite-bands/  To clarify, the only difference in a Tiff in the graphics world and a GeoTiff in the mapping world is the inclusion of a spatial reference.  In the graphics world, what I'm trying to do would be combining channels (instead of an image that has blue-green-red channels, the output would have one channel).

Comment: The problem is that the term "composite RGB TIFF" appears to have no meaning outside the GIS world and its software documentation, and I haven't seen any documentation (including what you linked) that describes what this term means in terms of the desired technical characteristics of a conforming TIFF.  If you have an example of a publicly accessible composite RGB TIFF file that I can download and examine, maybe I can provide further help.  Otherwise, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Just noting an update to the process utilizing the `terra` package. Process is very similar but there are some different parameters.

```r
r <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))

# a little forced as RGB is already assigned in this image... 
RGB(r) <- 1:3 

# export as geotiff -- again force due to input file example... 
writeRaster(x = r, filename = "rgb2.tif",datatype="INT1U",filetype = "GTiff")
```

I've been using with NAIP imagery successfully.

Comment: the argument `filetype = "GTiff"` (implied by the filename) and `gdal="TFW=YES"` (georeferencing is stored in the tif file) are redundant

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've edit the post to remove the redundant information.